# Generate a waveform image from an audio file

Tags: python, linux, audio, sox

Building a python application that converts raw audio files into wave using sox on a linux system. I want it to be able to generate an image (PNG or Jpeg) of the audio waveform pattern but I am unable to find a command line tool or python package that will do this. Not being an experience Python programmer my options are limited.

There are several linux applications available that require a running desktop (Gtk) which I do not have. These are useless.
http://www.baudline.com
http://quickplot.sourceforge.net/

GnuPlot and Octave seem to only be able to produce spectrograph's which is not what I am trying to do.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can get the raw audio data as a list of numbers, you can use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) to draw your waveform as a chart. The code would look something like this:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(raw_audio_data)
```

Comment: and scikits.audiolab is the way of getting the raw audio into an numpy array so it can be fed into matplotlib.

Thanks for point me in the right direction :)